# Google Analytics Data API shows different count than web ui

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am getting less count than actual web ui that I download as csv.
There are around 35k entries but I am getting only 600 something.

Here is my code.

```
dimensions = ["sessionSource","customEvent:order_id","date","platform"]
metrics =  ['sessions']
request = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "startDate": "2022-10-15",
          "endDate": "2022-10-17"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": [{'name': name} for name in dimensions],
      "metrics": [{'name': name} for name in metrics],
      "limit": 10,
      "return_property_quota": True,
      "keep_empty_rows": True,
      "data_loss_from_other_row": False
    }
  ]
}
analytics = build('analyticsdata', 'v1beta', credentials=credentials)
response = analytics.properties().batchRunReports(property=property_id, 
body=request).execute()
report_data = defaultdict(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see `limit` is set to 10 in your query. If this is set, [the response will only contain 10 rows](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/batchRunReports#runreportrequest).

Comment: I have increased the limit but it doesn't help